# GStreamer high quality screen recording with audio

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm trying to create an RTSP stream from the desktop screen and internal sound using GStreamer. Up to now, I've left RTSP aside to create a stable pipline and saved it into a file. I got:

```
GST_DEBUG=3 gst-launch-1.0 -v -e \
    ximagesrc use-damage=false \
    ! videorate \
    ! videoconvert  \
    ! "video/x-raw,framerate=30/1" \
    ! x264enc intra-refresh=true speed-preset=6 vbv-buf-capacity=0 qp-min=21 pass=qual quantizer=12 byte-stream=true key-int-max=30  bitrate=128 speed-preset=ultrafast tune=zerolatency \
    ! video/x-h264,profile=high \
    ! queue2 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 \
    ! muxer.video_0 \
    pulsesrc \
    ! "audio/x-raw,channels=2,rate=48000" \
    ! queue2 max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 \
    ! opusenc bitrate=128 \
    ! muxer.audio_0 \
    mp4mux name=muxer \
    ! filesink location=test.mp4
```

My problem is that although the general quality is good, I have some lags and "bumps" in the stream from time to time, so the audio isn't that smooth and so does the video. I'm looking for ways to make this pipeline better, but can't find it. Would love to get any help!

BTW, I also tried that with ffmpeg, but unfortunately it was laggy as well:

```
 ffmpeg -re -f x11grab -video_size 1920x1080 -r 60 -s 1920x1080 -an -i :0 -i watermark.png -filter_complex [1]lut=a=val*0.65[a];[0][a]overlay=(10):(main_h-overlay_h-10) -f pulse -ac 2 -ar 48000 -vn -i default -f mpegts -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -c:a copy -b:v 1200000 -bf 0 -map 0:v:0 -c:v libvpx -b:v 1000k -deadline realtime -cpu-used 4 -protocol_whitelist pipe,udp,rtp -f tee "RTSP sources..."
```

though that's out of this question topic.

Comment: I see that you are disabling all the default properties of `queue2`, wouldn't those help rather than just using the queue element for multithreading? Have you done this to avoid any one of the pipelines to lag behind the other?